# Get user's detailed newsfeed(wall) posts in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to build a project to know users' behavior when they surf facebook website, especially the advertisements showing in their timeline wall. I have learned the basic idea of facebook graph api, knowing how to access the users' information and their feeds. However, I found that the feeds returned by facebook graph api is not "exactly" what user really see when they open facebook url in their browser. First, in graph api, it doesn't show the advertisements posted by sponsors. Second, the feeds returned by facebook api seem only regarding to my own posts(e.g. the photo tagging me, the posts tagging me). So, I would like to know how to access these information to rebuild a testbed that looks like exactly same as  the real facebook website to record people reaction to it and continue my research?

Any idea is welcome ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really possible or rather I don't know any API (Facebook/Twitter/etc) that would do this to their third-party developers. The point of the API is to pull user data, not ads.

Also it sounds like you are using `/me/posts` or`/me/feed` instead of `/me/home`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I might sort to other method to keep this research, e.g., plugging some fake ads rather than the real ads provided by facebook ^^